# How to approximate continuous function from discrete uneven interval value?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, resampling

To clarify, I have a discrete value of an unknown distribution. The value of this distribution domain is from 0 to 1. But the value which the discrete value is sampled has an unknown interval.

For example if I have a function of `f(x) = x`. And the data I have the f(x) value of `[0.1, 0.7, 1.0]`, so the x value were sampled at `[0.1, 0.7, 1.0]` respectively. But assume I don't know the x value. So how can I approximate the f function, or at least approximate the `x` value for each `f(x)` on an unknown function?

The incorrect way that I can think of is to use `x` value evenly anyway. So the paired value will be `(0, 0.1), (0.5, 0.7), (1.0, 1.0)` and then use assumption what kind of `f(x)` function would be. In this case is a linear function. So I can solve for least squared for that.

Some floating idea is to use neuron network to approximate `f(x)`. And somehow use `KL-divergence` with the output (but I don't know how).

But is there a theory in statistics that deal with these kind of problem? If so, please let me know

Thank you in advance

Comment: Love this question. What I'd try to do is to fit a continuous/differentiable gaussian process to your data but also treating $x$ as a parameter. This would undeniably be expensive - so alternatively, you could represent the function as a smooth spline and treat the x variables as parameters. This would be an unidentifiable model, but if you post some data, I'd love to try and see (later) if this approach can work.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I don't have the actual data yet, so this is more theoretical on how to approach. But I believed that I can generated a mock data with `numpy` if you want some.

Comment: Note that there could probably be an infinite number of functions that you can generate with my example above, so the function that you do end up with would be really sensitive to assumptions and initial values for the optimiser

Comment: I see, the assumption is important to what the model will fit. But the observed data is continuous natural phenomena. For example, let say I have an observation data of a tadpole. which has 6 labels as follows eggs, tadpole with tail, tadpole with hind legs, tadpole with 4 legs, young frog, and adult frog. These were periodically observed as record. But there is no clear define way to tell when the transformation of each stage occurred. In this case what should I do?
If we use Gaussian mixture model, I think we can fit all the stage with 6 Gaussians, and then find the boundary. But should I?

Comment: By mean, you have a pool full of tadpole, and you can only count them by scoop them up. But we can estimate the true distribution of the population by using multiple sampling (scooping). The problem with using 6 Gaussian is I cannot tell if the distribution is actually a Gaussian per each stage or not. So what do you think?

Comment: If you've got numeric data that defines the "stage" of a tadpole, like mass maybe, I dunno, you could use a gaussian process to fit the unobserved time series of the mass, conditioned on the periodic observations that you do have. If instead, you only have the stage descriptions, you could try to model this as a kind of a Markov process with a transition matrix. Since you know that a frog can't transform back into a tadpole, you'd know that the frog -> tadpole probability is zero, and so on. You could fit a time inhomogeneous Markov process and represent the rates of transition as a spline/GP

Comment: Okay, I've got some idea now. So either a Gaussian Process or Markov Process with Transition Matrix would do the job. Thanks for the insight